# Get subclassed navigationController of current ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, subclass

I have a setup, where I subclassed UINavigationController to add a property holding a reference to another ViewController

```
class NavControllerWithReference: UINavigationController { 
    public var referenceToOtherVC: OtherVC? 
}
```

Now when I am in one of the ViewControllers inside this subclassed NavigationController, I want to access the reference property. For a "normal" NavigationController I would typically just access the `navigationController` property, which would return the navigationController. Obviously, it returns it as UINavigationController, even though it is subclassed, and I cannot do something like:

```
let navC = navigationController
if navC is [NavControllerWithReference] {  
    print("Yes")
}
```

This just tells me that:

> "Cast from UINavigationController to unrelated type NavControllerWithReference always fails".

How can I access the `referenceToOtherVC` from the child view controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
guard let nav = self.navigationController as? NavControllerWithReference  else { return }
print(nav.referenceToOtherVC)
```